# How to get all elements in a python list between key word elements?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list 'test_list':

```
test_list = ['garbage','######## KEY WORD ONE ####', 'data1', 'data2', '### KEY WORD TWO ######', 'junk']
```

I want to parse the list and get the elements only between key words one and two. I know I will have to use a for loop along with the
'in' operator for substring matching, but I'm not sure how to put it all together. The number of #s is variable so I need to use substring matching, no index function. If there's a more 'pythonic' way to do this feel free to suggest!

Desired result:

```
['data1', 'data2']
```

Comment: Use `.index()` to get the indexes of the keywords. Then use a list slice to get what's between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two indices (e.g. `ind1`, `ind2`) to find the key words. Then, slice the original list with the aid of these two indices.

```
test_list = ['garbage','######## KEY WORD ONE ####', 'data1', 'data2', '### KEY WORD TWO ######', 'junk']

ind1 = -1
ind2 = -1
for ind, item in enumerate(test_list):
    if "KEY WORD ONE" in item:
        ind1 = ind
    if "KEY WORD TWO" in item:
        ind2 = ind
    if ind1!=-1 and ind2!=-1:
        break

result_list = test_list[ind1+1:ind2]

print(result_list)
```

Print:

```
['data1', 'data2']
```

To find the indices, with one loop is enough and you can break the loop once you have found both key words. I guess it is faster than calling the builtin `index` function twice, which would run two loops to find both indices. However, you need less lines with the aforementioned function.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use index but it returns the first occured index in the list. If your keyword1 and keyword2 will occur only once then you can use the following.

```
id_one = test_list.index("#KEYWORD ONE")
id_two = test_list.index("#KEYWORD TWO")
print(test_list[id_one+1:id_two])
```

Comment: this could work but my key words need to use substring matching due to inconsistent #s. thanks though!

Comment: Your code gives the following error "#KEYWORD ONE" is not in list

Comment: @DavidDuran If keyword is not in the list it would give the error. If you need a substring matching then you should use regular expression inside the index function.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you -

```
test_list = ['garbage','######## KEY WORD ONE ####', 'data1', 'data2', '### KEY WORD TWO ######', 'junk']

start = test_list.index('######## KEY WORD ONE ####')
end = test_list.index('### KEY WORD TWO ######')
print(test_list[start + 1:end])
```

Comment: This is helpful, but could you [edit] and explain how it works, for OP's sake? Just a sentence or two is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming -- keyword -- `'######## KEY WORD ONE ####'` appears before -- `'### KEY WORD TWO ######'` in the list.

```
test_list = ['garbage','######## KEY WORD ONE ####', 'data1', 'data2', '### KEY WORD TWO ######', 'junk']
start = -1
end = -1

result_list = []

for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
    if (test_list[i] == '######## KEY WORD ONE ####'):
        start = i
    if (test_list[i] == '### KEY WORD TWO ######'):
        end = i
        break

if start != -1 and end != -1:
    # meaning both keywords are found
    result_list = test_list[start+1:end]

print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test_list = ['garbage','######## KEY WORD ONE ####', 'data1', 'data2', '### KEY WORD TWO ######', 'junk']
new_list = []

for x in test_list:
    if 'KEY WORD ONE' in x:
        new_list.append(test_list[test_list.index(x)+1])
    elif 'KEY WORD TWO' in x:
        new_list.append(test_list[test_list.index(x)-1])
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on [David Duran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63289017/4518341), but using a single loop to find the keywords and build the list. This uses a classic looping construct with a flag variable.

```
result = []
start_found = False
for item in test_list:
    if start_found:
        if "KEY WORD TWO" in item:
            break
        else:
            result.append(item)
    elif "KEY WORD ONE" in item:
        start_found = True

print(result)  # -> ['data1', 'data2']
```